# Disable "unlock" sound in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, system-sounds

I hate when my PC gives me feedback with sounds, so the first thing I do after I install windows is disable all of them. Recently, I upgraded to Windows 8 and I can't find the option to disable the *unlock* sound.

I have all sounds disabled (including logon and logoff sounds), but this particular sound isn't in the list.

I tried deleting the file and it told me that I require permission from trusted installer. Then I rebooted into my other windows partition and tried again. I got the same message, even after taking ownership of the folder.

Finally I tried changing the location of the sound to point to an empty wav via regedit (in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps.Default\WindowsUnlock). Again, nothing happened.

How can I get rid of this annoyance for good?

Comment: http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-options-to-customize-windows-logon-logoff-exit-and-unlock-sounds-in-windows-8/

Comment: thanks! I had seen that article but didn't read it fully... I thought it just talked about the cpl items. Why Microsoft would do such a thing is beyond me though. BTW you should post that as an answer so I can mark the question as solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft has removed options to change or disable Windows logon, logoff, exit and unlock event sounds from Windows 8 sound settings present in Control Panel.  These steps will help you in bringing those sound options back in Windows 8.

1. Press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> key combination to launch RUN dialog box then type `regedit` and press Enter. It'll open the Registry Editor.
2. Now go to following key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\EventLabels`
3. Under this key, you'll find several sub-keys which are actually associated with all the sound options which are shown in Sound applet present in Control Panel.

   Now scroll down a little and you'll find "*WindowsLogon*" key. Click on the key and in right-side pane, you'll notice the DWORD *ExcludeFromCPL* which would be set to `1`.
4. Double-click on the DWORD and change its value to `0` or simply delete the DWORD.
5. Do the same for other keys as well such as *WindowsLogoff*, *WindowsUnlock* and *SystemExit*.
6. Close Registry Editor and open Sound applet from Control Panel and you'll get the options to customize Windows logon, logoff, exit and unlock sounds back.

[Source/More Info](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-options-to-customize-windows-logon-logoff-exit-and-unlock-sounds-in-windows-8/)