# Play sound when Windows 8 unlocks

Tags: windows-8, audio

I have the opposite problem of [this user](https://superuser.com/questions/652363/disable-unlock-sound-in-windows-8) – I want to get Windows to make a sound when I unlock it, but I can't figure out how to. I followed the instructions that are linked there to modify my registry such that it shows up in the sound applet, but even though it's there and has a sound selected it's not making any noise. What do I have to do to enable it?

Note: other system sounds work, so that's not the problem. I've tried restarting just in case there was some weird thing which need a reboot but that didn't work either. I'm not sure what else to look for.